# elastic search fulltext search on multiple index

Tags: elasticsearch

Design Query for elasticsearch:

I have 10 tables in my mysql database : news, emails,  etc. Which i would sync into elasticsearch. and i want to search across all these tables in the same go.
There are no relationship in tables and all have `txt` field in them.  Just want to search in `txt` field .. so should i have multiple index or just 1 index.

How should i organize my indices:

**Option 1 :** Should i have just one elasticsearch index(with an attribute of table type) for all the tables

OR

**Option 2 :** Should i have just multiple elasticsearch  index for all the tables

Considering:

- want to make combined query in multiple data source ordered by hits . Example : search all email + news   ..
- or single query to only search email or news only

Comment: Needs more context.  Generally speaking, you'll need to flatten your tables... The flattening depends on what the table relationships are? What's a concrete query you want to implement?

Comment: there are no relationship in tables and all have txt field in them .. just want to seach in txt field .. so should i have multiple index or just 1 index ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have multiple indices and query any number of them at any given time:

```
POST emails/_doc
{
  "txt": "abc"
}

POST news/_doc
{
  "txt": "ab"
}

GET emails,news/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "txt", 
      "query": "ab OR abc"
    }
  }
}
```

Wildcard index names are [supported](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html#multi-index) too in case you've got, say, timestamp-bucketed names such as `emails_2020`, `emails_2019` etc:

```
GET em*,ne*/_search
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could use the msearch to search multiple indices:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html